# CheckDlgButton with CComboBox

Tags: winapi, combobox, mfc

I though `CheckDlgButton` can only used with radio button (`BS_RADIOBUTTON`) or checkbox (`BS_AUTOCHECKBOX`).

But based on what I witness in a project that I need to maintain, it seems `CheckDlgButton` can be used with CComboBox.
Let's say I define a `CComboBox` such as following:

```
COMBOBOX        IDC_NAME_LST,284,283,55,55,CBS_DROPDOWNLIST | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
```

Then I call CheckDlgButton on it as following:

```
CheckDlgButton(IDC_NAME_LST,state);
```

I tried to set `state` to `BST_CHECKED`, `BST_INDETERMINATE` and `BST_UNCHECKED` alternatively but nothing happened.

I want to know if it is common to use CheckDlgButton with something else rather than radio button or checkbox.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. You claim that *X* works, while at the same time *X* doesn't work. So does it or does it not work?

Comment: I meant to say in the code I am working with, they used  CheckDlgButton with CComboBox. I don't understand why they did that so I tried to replicate it myself  but nothing happened.

Comment: What is using [`CheckDlgButton`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-checkdlgbutton) on a combo box supposed to do? The documentation doesn't mention combo boxes. If you have seen this in a project, it's most likely wrong. It's probably normal that it doesn't do anything, BTW _what_ should it do?

Comment: `CheckDlgButton` takes a control **ID** as its argument. Control IDs need not be globally unique. Who knows, maybe that ID is used in several places, and the one you are looking at is not the one the code refers to.

Comment: Could be leftover going from checkbox or radiobuttons to combobox. Is combobox selection correctly initialized? If not may be you need to select correct item (`CB_SETCURSEL`).

Comment: Please elaborate on "But based on what I witness in a project that I need to maintain, it seems CheckDlgButton can be used with CComboBox.". Why do you believe that it might/should work?